# Go from store path to derivation in nix repl

Tags: nix

One of the packages I'm trying to debug is hidden inside a few links of derivations. I've found a reference in one of the paths, but that's a string I can't pull inside of `nix repl`. Is there a way to go from nix store path (which doesn't exist yet, because that's the derivation that fails) to a nix derivation object?

```
nix-repl> de.dev.packages.hie-bios.pkgs  
"[{\"paths\":[\"/nix/store/f04qyvqaj6s6y5f5a7svpfppsq5wx2p6-haskell-ide-engine-ghc864-7541d1ec71\"],\"priority\":-864}]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem like you can. The Nix language does let you access the string context, but the string context is not intended to reproduce a derivation, let alone the original expression that the derivation came from.

```
nix-repl> :p builtins.getContext "example string ${(import <nixpkgs> {}).hello.outPath}"  
{ "/nix/store/m2capxzda4ams4fi3awmriz7hfkdxyp9-hello-2.10.drv" = { outputs = [ "out" ]; }; }
```

Technically you can read the derivation contents and parse the ATerm inside etc etc, but that's really not supported. It doesn't handle string contexts, probably won't let you build anything and will kill your dog. And even then, you don't get the original expression back.

```
nix-repl> :p builtins.readFile (builtins.head (builtins.attrNames (builtins.getContext "example string ${(import <nixpkgs> {}).hello.outPath}")))
"Derive([(\"out\",\"/nix/[...]
```

It's probably best to solve your `hie-bios` problem directly.